# Raycast2D not working with LayerMask

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

I am attempting to use a Raycast2D to detect if an attack has hit an enemy.  I created a LayerMask for the "Enemy" layer and I have an object with a collider on the "Enemy" layer.  I have no problem hitting the collider without using a LayerMask, however when I do, I get nothing back. What am I missing here?

```
LayerMask EnemyLayer;

void Start ()
{
    EnemyLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer ("Enemy");
}

public void BasicAttack()
{
    PlayerVitality.Stamina = 0;

    Vector2 attackDirection = CalculateAttackDirection ();
    float attackDamage = CalculateDamage (BasicAttackDamage);
    Debug.Log (EnemyLayer.value);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(transform.position.x + 2, transform.position.y), attackDirection, BasicAttackDistance, EnemyLayer.value);

    if (hit.collider != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("You hit: " + hit.collider.gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The casting between `int` and `LayerMask` can be a bit confusing.

When you call `LayerMask.NameToLayer("Enemy")`, you get the layer index. Let's assume that "Enemy" is layer 7, so that call would return `7`. So far, so good, but a layer index is not the same as the bitwise layer mask that is used by the raycast function.

In order to mask layer seven, you set the seventh bit: `1 << 7`, which is `128`. If you're not familiar with bitwise operators such as `|` bitwise OR, `&` bitwise AND, or `<<` left shift, you can look up some other tutorials to understand bitmasks.

So, you're passing in `7` (bits 0, 1 and 2) where you need to pass `128` (bit 7)

Long story short, you need to turn your index into a bitmask.

Either of these will work:

```
//get layer index, use it to make a bitmask
EnemyLayer = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Enemy");

//ask unity for a bitmask directly
EnemyLayer = LayerMask.GetMask("Enemy");
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me using ``RaycastHit2D ray = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, dir, Mathf.Infinity, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("player"));``